# Cómo solucionar el Error de importación de servicio virtualizado en Virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

tengo Win10 instalado en mi laptop y necesito importar un archivo .ova x virtual box para hacer un trabajo. No he podido lograrlo aún, me sale una ventana de error con la advertencia Fallo al importar el servicio virtualizado. Me aparece: Error reading OVA y después la dirección del archivo .ova El código de error es 0x80BB0005.
Porfa si alguien puede ayudarme